# How to call Batch file Or powershell from informatica command task

Tags: powershell

I am trying to call Batch .BAT file from command Task of informatica and same with powershell .PS1 also which has multiple commands. Workflow is successful but does nothing. Though the same PS1 script when run on powershell windows it works fine.
This powershell script runs fine on command task in informatica :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$PMRootDir\foldername\SrcFiles\filename*.csv"
```

But when used multiple commands it does nothing

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$PMRootDir\foldername\SrcFiles\filename*.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Length -lt 100} | Remove-Item
```

Comment: Maybe the length of all csv files is greater than 100?

Comment: @JosefZ Issue is how to call the above script from Informatica powercenter command task.

Comment: @Goks... Try executing it as `powershell -executionpolicy bypass -command "Get-ChildItem -Path "$PMRootDir\foldername\SrcFiles\filename*.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Length -lt 100} | Remove-Item"` and see if that does the trick. It sounds like it needs to run the PS commands with PowerShell.exe as per this example provided.